# Is there a way to access my mac remotely by using browser only?

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to be able to browse/search my files, send email... nothing fancy like watch the movie and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use logmein https://secure.logmein.com/

After installing and setting things up you will just need your browser wherever you are.

Comment: Brilliant! Works!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a remote access web-based application such as [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com), [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/).  You have to download the app on the host machine and should be able to connect in through the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are also browser-based VNC clients like [noVNC](http://novnc.com/info.html):

**noVNC is an open source VNC client using HTML5** (WebSockets, Canvas). It requires a browser with HTML5 support (this means it works on all major browsers but not on IE 10).

noVNC follows the standard VNC protocol, but unlike other VNC clients it does require WebSockets support. Many servers include support (e.g. [x11vnc/libvncserver](http://libvncserver.sourceforge.net/), [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org/), and [MobileVNC](http://www.smartlab.at/mobilevnc/)), but for the others you need to use a WebSockets to TCP socket proxy. noVNC has a sister project [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify) that provides a simple such proxy.

See the [noVNC GitHub Readme file](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/blob/master/README.md) for more information.

Comment: noVNC uses raw format, so it does not speak well with Apple Remote Desktop VNC.

Comment: To setup guacamole as a docker instance should be another possible way.